# Android decomplie strange problems

Tags: android, decompiling, apktool, dex2jar

I have catch a strange problem about Android decomplie.
For research, I decomplie an Android apk by **apktool** and **dex2jar**, every thing seems ok, but when I use **JD-GUI** to open the decomplied .jar file, I cannot found any **Android Activity** class file in it, the interested was I saw the **AndroidManifest.xml** file which has wrote some activity path in it, and I promise I cannot found these classes file from those path, what's wrong with it? and how can do it?

--[Updated]--
I found that not only Activity class file not exists, but also some custom widget class file too, I saw some layout xml has used custom widget, but cannot found them real file. is there really in some way can hide the class file prevent others decompile?

[image] 
[image]

Comment: If it can be run, it can be decompiled.

Comment: of course it can be install and run, but after decompiled, some class file cannot be found, whatever use JD-GUI tool to read .jar, or use apktool decompiled and search smali file, all missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disassembling the `.dex` file contains only the Java source code. This file is commonly `classes.dex`, but for multi dex applications can exist anywhere in the `classes#.dex` where `#` is some number `>= 1`.

You will not find `AndroidManifest.xml` and various layout files in the `.dex` file. These are located elsewhere (`resources.arsc`, `AndroidManifest.xml` and `res/`) and only decoded to human-readable form with something like apktool.

Additionally, you can't hide anything. If the application runs on Android, there is a good chance it can be decoded. Obfuscation can help, but won't prevent viewing of source.